# iCloud synchronise content keep asset URL and photo URL?

Tags: ios, core-data, icloud

I have an app that uses Core Data and the Core Data entity stores asset URL for Photos from Apple's Photo app, song asset URL for the music file from Apple's Music app and lastly, stores a local audio.caf file in the documents directory (the entity itself stores the file path to the audio.caf file, not the file itself).

The two questions I have are:

1. What I want to know is, can Core Data and iCloud sync this content across to multiple devices and keep the URL the same?

I am concerned that after the iCloud does the sync, the asset URL from the previous iPad doesn't exist on the new iPad (even if the photos, music and audio files are there)

2. Can iCloud sync the audio.caf that is stored in my app's Document directory (the folder intended for iCloud to sync content). I would assume if it can, it would take some time since the audio.caf file is a audio recording, at 44100 Hz sample rate.

I'm trying to gauge whether using iCloud would work or whether we need to build a server to allow user's to keep their content synchronised.

### Background Info About My App

My app is kind of like a slideshow app that uses photos from the Apple Photos app loaded through ALAssets.

The music for my slideshow is referenced from the Apple's Music app.

I manually record an audio file in CAF format and store it in the Documents folder within my app (this file can be synced I assume, although would take a while).

My app uses Core Data to store the "Slideshow" but the Slideshow entity only stores references to the files, not the photo and music files themselves.

Ultimately, I want to have the app open up on another iPad and that iCloud syncs the Slideshow across, keeping the photos and music files in tact. Ideally, I don't want users to have to manually reconstruct their Slideshow, reorder the photo, repick the music etc.

Is what I'm trying to do possible?

Do I resort to iCloud Drive? Create some sort of Powerpoint file and back that up? That would involve the user manually exporting and importing right?

**How does Apple's Keynote do it?**

They seem to use something called iCloud Drive, does the Keynote app stores all the photos and audio with the slides in a binary form, then upload to the iCloud Drive server and hence why other devices can pull down the same content without the slides needing to deal with broken file paths?

Comment: Hmmm, I think I might need to resort to cloning the photos into my own app's Document directory and changing Core Data to store only the unique name of the image rather than the actual ALAssets URL, this way iCloud can sync, and my app only needs to know the file name. It of course would mean my code need to search for that photo in the common Document directory intended for iCloud.

Comment: I'm in a similar predicament. I was just hoping that the URLs for assets would be the same for images shared across devices. This way, I wouldn't need to duplicate the images, and increase the user's iCloud storage space. Your approach is probably the right way to go, it would just be nice if the URLs worked across the cloud.

Comment: I think we do need to copy the image into our own app's then let iCloud sync those photos across. Our app's Core Data should probably just store the name of the file, then when we need to search for the file in the documents directory, we prepend the path to the filename.